# How can window.open be used with the HTML5 Audio tag?

Tags: wordpress, dom-events, html5-audio, window.open

I'm trying to find out if I can trigger a new window when the play button is pressed on an html5 audio player.

Here's what my client wants:

- Press "play" on the html5 audio player on a page
- Song plays and a new, sized window pops up displaying the lyrics of
  the song

My brain immediately wants to treat the play button like an `on.click` behavior that would trigger a `window.open`... but I can't find if this is possible.

By the way, using a Flash player is not an option in this situation.

Bonus:  A way to do this using the WordPress plugin PowerPress..?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An HTML5 video player emits a `play` JavaScript event when the video starts playing. You can add an event listener for it, or add an `onplay` attribute to the `<video>` tag.

http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html

Comment: My inquiry is specifically about the HTML5 audio player, not the video player.  Is there a comparable media event in the audio player? I assume so, but couldn't find html5-specific documentation on w3.org.

Thanks!